# Why my OS is not loaded by my bootloader file?

Tags: assembly, bootloader

I have a problem with the creation of an OS.
I have 2 files (bootloader.s && kernel.s)
but when I compile thoses 2 files and exec there with

```
as -o bootloader.o bootloader.s
ld -o bootloader.bin --oformat binary -e init -Ttext 0x7c00 -o bootloader.bin bootloader.o
qemu-system-x86_64 bootloader.bin
```

nothing append (just : "Booting from Hard Disk ...")

I didn't found solution on https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/asm-boot-loader-91783
and the same for others tutorials.

bootloader.s

```
.code16 # use 16 bits
.set BASE, 0x1000
.set KSIZE, 1
.global init

init:
    mov $0x100, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov %ax, %es

    # initialisation du segment de pile
    mov $0x8000, %ax
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov $0xf000, %sp

    mov $0x0e,  %ah

    in  $0x64,  %al
    test    $1, %al
    jz  init_next

    in  $0x60,  %al
    cmp $224,   %al
    je  init_next

init_next:

    mov     BASE, %ax
    mov     %ax, %es
    xor     %bx, %bx

# charger le noyau
    mov $0x02, %ah
    mov KSIZE, %al
    mov $0, %ch
    mov $2, %cl
    mov $0, %dh
    mov $0, %dl
    int $0x13
    mov $'F', %al
    int $0x10


# saut vers le kernel
    jmp BASE


bootdrv: .int 0


.fill 510-(.-init), 1, 0
.word 0xaa55

.include "kernel.s"
```

kernel.s

```
.code16
.global init
.org 0x1000

start:
    mov $0x1000, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov %ax, %es

    # initialisation du segment de pile
    mov $0x8000, %ax
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov $0xf000, %sp

    mov $0x0e,  %ah

    in  $0x64,  %al
    test    $1, %al
    jz  next

    in  $0x60,  %al
    cmp $224,   %al
    je  next

data:
    msg: .asciz "Hello world !"
    msg2: .asciz "I hope you're well : "
    test_int: .int 0
    #msg3: .asciz "Just a test for the size of the bootloader"

print_str:
    push %ax
    .print_str__run:
        lodsb
        cmp $0, %al
        je  .print_str__done
        int $0x10
        jmp .print_str__run
    .print_str__done:
        pop %ax
        ret

print_nl:
    push %ax
    .print_nl__run:
        mov $10, %al
        int $0x10
        mov $13, %al
        int $0x10

        pop %ax
        ret


input:
    .input__run:
        in  $0x64,  %al
        and $1, %al
        jz  .input__run

        in  $0x60,  %al # get input keyboard

        mov %al,    %bl
        cmp $0x0,   %bl
        je  .input__run

        shr $4, %bl # move to right 4 bits
        cmp $0x0, %bl
        je  .input__number

        jmp .input__letter


        .input__number:
            add $47,    %al
            int $0x10
            jmp .input__done

        .input__letter:
            cmp $0x10,  %al
            je .input__letter__a
            cmp $0x11,  %al
            je .input__letter__z
            cmp $0x12,  %al
            je .input__letter__e
            cmp $0x13,  %al
            je .input__letter__r
            cmp $0x14,  %al
            je .input__letter__t
            cmp $0x15,  %al
            je .input__letter__y
            cmp $0x16,  %al
            je .input__letter__u
            cmp $0x17,  %al
            je .input__letter__i
            cmp $0x18,  %al
            je .input__letter__o
            cmp $0x19,  %al
            je .input__letter__p
            cmp $0x1e,  %al
            je .input__letter__q
            cmp $0x1f,  %al
            je .input__letter__s
            cmp $0x20,  %al
            je .input__letter__d
            cmp $0x21,  %al
            je .input__letter__f
            cmp $0x22,  %al
            je .input__letter__g
            cmp $0x23,  %al
            je .input__letter__h
            cmp $0x24,  %al
            je .input__letter__j
            cmp $0x25,  %al
            je .input__letter__k
            cmp $0x26,  %al
            je .input__letter__l
            cmp $0x27,  %al
            je .input__letter__m
            cmp $0x2c,  %al
            je .input__letter__w
            cmp $0x2d,  %al
            je .input__letter__x
            cmp $0x2e,  %al
            je .input__letter__c
            cmp $0x2f,  %al
            je .input__letter__v
            cmp $0x30,  %al
            je .input__letter__b
            cmp $0x31,  %al
            je .input__letter__n
            cmp $0x39,  %al
            je .input__letter__space

            jmp .input__run

            .input__letter__a:
                mov $'a',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__z:
                mov $'z',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__e:
                mov $'e',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__r:
                mov $'r',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__t:
                mov $'t',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__y:
                mov $'y',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__u:
                mov $'u',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__i:
                mov $'i',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__o:
                mov $'o',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__p:
                mov $'p',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__q:
                mov $'q',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__s:
                mov $'s',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__d:
                mov $'d',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__f:
                mov $'f',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__g:
                mov $'g',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__h:
                mov $'h',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__j:
                mov $'j',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__k:
                mov $'k',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__l:
                mov $'l',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__m:
                mov $'m',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__w:
                mov $'w',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__x:
                mov $'x',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__c:
                mov $'c',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__v:
                mov $'v',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__b:
                mov $'b',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__n:
                mov $'n',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

            .input__letter__space:
                mov $' ',   %al
                int $0x10
                jmp .input__done

    .input__done:
        ret

next:

.key_wait:
    in  $0x64,  %al
    and $1, %al
    jz  .key_wait

    in  $0x60,  %al

    cmp $0x10,  %al # 'a' pressed
    je .code

    mov %al,    %bl
    cmp $0x0,   %bl
    je  .key_wait

    shr $4, %bl
    cmp $0x0, %bl
    je  .number

    jmp .normal


    .number:
        add $47,    %al
        int $0x10
        jmp .key_wait

    .normal:
        int $0x10
        jmp .key_wait

.code:
    #mov $8, %al
    #mov %al, test_int
    call print_nl
    mov $msg, %si
    call print_str
    call print_nl
    mov $msg2, %si
    call print_str
    code__input:
    call input
    mov $0x0, %al
```

Comment: At the very least you need to fix your `jmp BASE` as that jumps to `0:1000` not `1000:0`. Learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov     BASE, %ax
> mov     %ax, %es
> xor     %bx, %bx
> ```

Seeing that the *kernel.s* file has an `.org 0x1000` directive, we know that the `.set BASE, 0x1000` refers to the linear address 0x1000. In order to have BIOS load the kernel we should set `%es:%bx` to 0x0000:0x1000.

```
xor %ax, %ax
mov %ax, %es
mov BASE, %bx
```

---

> ```
> init:
>     mov $0x100, %ax
>     mov %ax, %ds
>     mov %ax, %es
> ```

Because your *bootloader.s* file uses an origin of 7C00h, the correct setting for `%ds` and `%es` is zero:

```
init:
    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov %ax, %es
```

---

> ```
> .org 0x1000
>
> start:
>     mov $0x1000, %ax
>     mov %ax, %ds
>     mov %ax, %es
> ```

Because your *kernel.s* file uses `.org 0x1000`, the correct setting for `%ds` and `%es` is zero:

```
.org 0x1000

start:
    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov %ax, %es
```

---

> ```
> mov $0, %dl
> int $0x13
> mov $'F', %al
> int $0x10
> ```

What is this `int $0x10` supposed to do?
If the `int $0x13` call was successfull then `%ah` would still contain 0x02, but that would lead to a non-sensical SetCursorPosition invokation, and if the `int $0x13` call was unsuccessfull then `%ah` would hold a status byte which would lead to invoking some random video BIOS call!

Tip 1: Always check the carry flag that BIOS reports to you so you can deal with errors...
Tip 2: Better leave out the `mov $0, %dl` instruction and use the value that BIOS put in the `%dl` register when it passed control to your bootloader.

---

> ```
>     cmp $224,   %al
>     je  next
>
> data:
>     msg: .asciz "Hello world !"
> ```

What happens when `%al` is not equal to 224? The execution falls through in some data, definitely not code!

I would suggest to take it one step at a time, and simplify your current code (both files) to **not use those keyboard related ports**.
Where keyboard input is needed you should use BIOS (like you're already using for anything else):

```
mov  ah, 00h   ; BIOS.WaitKeyboardKeypress
int  16h       ; -> AH is scancode, AL is ASCII code
```

Comment: Thanks for your time taken ^^
The int $0x10 was here for debugging, and I forgot to remove it.
I have made change and my kernel doesn't start  anymore.
I also change the
".global init"
in kernel.s, by
".global start"

Comment: After debugging, I found that when I want to print a char just before "jmp BASE", it is printed twice (and my kernel is not loaded). Thank you for the warning about Keyboard port, I have changed it. My code to print a letter, put just before jmp BASE
`
push %ax
mov $0x0a, %ah
mov $'G', %al
int $0x10
pop %ax
`

Comment: @Quenn3000 It is normal that your character 'G' gets printed twice. The BIOS function 0Ah ('WriteCharacter') uses `%cx` as a parameter that specifies the number of repetitions of the character. And because your code had previously loaded `%ch` with 0 for the cylinder number and `%cl` with 2 for the sector number, the `%cx` register still holds 2. Because of the many changes that are needed (and the fact that the kernel doesn't load), consider posting another question with all changes applied. Don't modify the current question!

Comment: Here is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71570137/why-my-os-kernel-is-not-loaded-by-my-bootloader
(I have simplified the kernel to be sure that the problem doesn't come from it).