# Why my OS kernel is not loaded by my bootloader?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

I have a problem with the creation of my bootloader in asm. When I try to execute my generated bin file, the program is executed until "jmp BASE" from my bootloader.s file and nothing is happening from my kernel.s file.

When I debug my bootloader and I try to print a char with

```
push %ax
push %cx
mov $0x01, %cx
mov $0x0a, %ah
mov $'B', %al
int $0x10
pop %cx
pop %ax
```

just before the "jmp BASE", the B character is printing.

Commands to compile and run

```
as -o bootloader.o bootloader.s
ld -o bootloader.bin --oformat binary -e init -Ttext 0x7c00 -o bootloader.bin bootloader.o
qemu-system-x86_64 bootloader.bin
```

bootloader.s

```
.code16 # use 16 bits
.set BASE, 0x1000
.set KSIZE, 1
.global init

init:
    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov %ax, %es

    # initialisation du segment de pile
    mov $0x8000, %ax
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov $0xf000, %sp

    jmp init_next

init_next:

    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ax, %es
    mov BASE, %bx

# charger le noyau
    mov $0x02, %ah
    mov KSIZE, %al
    mov $0, %ch
    mov $2, %cl
    mov $0, %dh
    int $0x13


# saut vers le kernel
    jmp BASE


bootdrv: .int 0


.fill 510-(.-init), 1, 0
.word 0xaa55

.include "kernel.s"
```

kernel.s

```
.code16
.global start
.org 0x1000

start:
    push %ax
    push %cx
    mov $0x01, %cx
    mov $0x0a, %ah
    mov $'L', %al
    int $0x10
    pop %cx
    pop %ax
```

- UPDATE
  I have tried to use an other way to compile my os, but it still don't work

the 0x13 interrupt return 0x01 in ah, "Invalid Command" (Wikipedia)

command

```
as -o bootloader.o bootloader.s
ld --oformat binary -e init -Ttext 0x7c00 -o bootloader.bin bootloader.o

as -o kernel.o kernel.s
ld --oformat binary -e start -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel.bin kernel.o

cat bootloader.bin kernel.bin > disk.bin

qemu-system-x86_64 disk.bin
```

Comment: You are missing `$` sign from `mov BASE, %bx` and `mov KSIZE, %al`. `.org 0x1000` does not do what you think it does, remove it for now. (In the long run, assemble and link the kernel separately with its own `-Ttext` or use a linker script.) Put a `jmp .` at the end to avoid going executing uninitialized memory.

Comment: I am not really good with linkers, but I have tried something (see the update)
(and thx for the time taken :))

Comment: It won't work like that. Linker scripts are black magic anyway. I recommend you just assemble and link the two files separately (use `-Ttext 0x1000` for the kernel) then simply append them together e.g. by `cat bootloader.bin kernel.bin > disk.bin`.

Comment: I have updated my question, and even with those changes it doesn't work

Comment: You did not fix the missing `$` signs.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer about this point, but when I try to put a '$' before BASE or KSIZE line 22 and 26, the program is not executed from those lines.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "not executed" but rest assured the `$` is required otherwise it will be a memory read. Works here.

Comment: By "not executed", it is that the code is not read by the computer. The code is compiled but not executed by qemu